# Inequality problem involving log function

Tags: calculus, analysis, contest-math

Given $|f(x+y)-f(x)-f(y)| \leq x+y$ for all $x > y > 0$, prove that real valued function $f$ satisfies the inequality $|\frac{f(x)}{x} - \frac{f(y)}{y}| \leq M(1+\log_2\frac{x}{y})$ where M is some constant. This was a previous contest problem in my university, but I couldn't solve it.